# Creating bean for custom module

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I have created the SLA workflow module in suitecrm. Now I want to get all records for SLA workflow module ("SLA_workflow"-module name).
I have try below code but I did not get any record.

```
$workflowbean=BeanFactory::newBean('SLA_workflow');
$slabean=BeanFactory::getBean('SLA_workflow');
```

Above both are not giving me records for SLA workflow module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve a single record `$workflowbean->retrieve($workflowbean_id)`
To retrieve a list of records its a bit more complex as you have to specify filtering and other details.

For example for the Accounts module (just tested on 7.11.2) it will be something like this:

```
      $moduleBean = BeanFactory::getBean("Accounts");
      $where=[" accounts.name like '%t%' "]; //This can be an array of where conditions
      $params['include_custom_fields']=true;
      $query = $moduleBean->create_new_list_query(" ORDER BY accounts.name ", implode(" AND ", $where), "", $params, $show_deleted = 0, '', false, null, $singleSelect = false);
      $offset=0;
      $limit=10;
      $max_per_page=10;
      $res=$moduleBean->process_list_query($query, $offset, $limit, $max_per_page, $where);
```

That should allow you to get a list of beans based on your search params